# Bootstrap Gate Drive

Tags: mppt

I did try to set this up in Mouser Blue Edition. Apparently vb and vs become connected at some point so the bootstrap capacitor can discharge itself. I haven't been able to see that happen in my simulator yet Mouser Blue encounters an unrecoverable problem and can't simulate anything (The second schematic is from Fairchilds):

[image]

I'm not sure I have it down really but if VB and VS are connected inside the IR2104 then it should look like this I think:
[image]

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a question about the weird behavior of your model, right? The wire between the diode and the capacitor is totally isolated as long as the diode is in reverse bias.

I would suggest adding a large (100 M\$\Omega\$) resistor in parallel with the capacitor and a similar resistor in parallel with the diode. There is always some leakage current across a capacitor or a diode, so this actually makes the component model more realistic. I bet the 5.99 V will pull down to 0 V in your model.